# How do I imitate system Photo App's "share to Facebook" UI?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit

[image]

It seems I cannot use "Popover" or "Form Sheet". Then how do I implement this?

I do not want to use a container view controller, or a view that is hidden.

Can I make a custom segue class to achieve this?

Comment: I want to add that I want to implement this effect on iPhone. Like a alert controller and it is translucent/blurred. It is presented modally with transparent dark view surrounded.

Comment: That's a `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: @rmaddy I mean above the UIActivityViewController, there is a window, title named "Facebook"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a custom view, it's an extension provided by the Facebook app. You can see more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/).